# Extracting Specific Info From H2, Edit and remove some dynamic values in imacros

Tags: javascript, automation, firefox-addon, imacros

I got stuck in this step please guide, I have code for automation, i am using imacros on firefox, this is my code:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=CLASS:admin EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(\"From\",\"\");")
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>FORM>TEXTAREA" CHARS="Hello,{{!VAR1}}"
```

class=*admin* contains data like this: "**From Syed Ali Jan, @syed_alijan**"

**Syed Ali Jan** (Dynamic Value, Changing with users name)
**@syed_alijan** (Dynamic Value, Changing with users id)

Is there anyway to split this text into two parts?
I replace "From" to (space), but not able to remove "Syed Ali Jan" text which is obviously changing with user name on everypage.
because, i just want the dynamic value of user id (i.e @syedalijan).

Thanks.

Comment: Im not to experienced with imacros, i dont know if people in this section are :( the peopl in [tag:imacros] should help hopefully

Comment: Someone help this guy out please.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the dynamic value ('@syed_alijan' in this case) change your third line of the code as follows:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.substr('{{!EXTRACT}}'.indexOf('@'))")
```